# Just django dynamic formset and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I use django dynamic formset and ajax to chekc the inventory. When I add a form, how to have ajax pick up change on the new form?

dynamic formset adding forms

```
    $('#form-inline tbody tr').formset({
addText: 'add link',
deleteText: 'remove',
prefix: 'ptpositions'
});
```

I loop the form in ajax but I don't think this is a good way.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

{% for forms in formset %}
$(".{{forms.stock.value}}").change( function(){
var symbol = $(".{{forms.stock.value}} option:selected").text();
{% endfor %}

{% for forms in formset %}
$.ajax({
    url: "{% url 'inventory:get_position' ptinventory_obj.id date %}",
    type: "GET",
    data: { 'product': product },
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        $(".{{forms.id.value}}_ouput").html(data.price);

    }});
    {% endfor %}

});

})
```

Now if I add form, then the ajax doesn't work.

edited

Now i just loop it once but the result is the same

```
$(document).ready(function(){

{% for forms in formset %}
$(".{{forms.stock.auto_id}}").change( function(){
var symbol = $(".{{forms.stock.auto_id}} option:selected").text();

$.ajax({
    url: "{% url 'inventory:get_position' ptinventory_obj.id date %}",
    type: "GET",
    data: { 'product': product },
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        $(".{{forms.inventory.auto_id}}").html(data.price);

    }});


});
{% endfor %}
})
```

The main issue I found is probably the output...when I add one form. None of the output is displayed. Not sure why....

I now realize the newly created form has None class which means the form.id.value is none before save. The inline position is not created yet. How do I give id to a formset instance that is not saved yet?

Edited

Ok, I figured what the problem is but don't know how to solve it
everytime i added a new form the form

```html
{% for forms in formset %} {{ forms.id }}


<tr class="dynamic">

  <td style="width:100px" class="{{forms.stock.auto_id}}">{{ forms.stock.errors }} {{ forms.stock}}{{forms.stock.fields.auto_id}}
  </td>

  <td style="width:100px">{{ forms.inventory.errors }} {{ forms.inventory}}
  </td>
```

The problem is the added new form {{forms.stock}}has a new id

but if I use {{forms.stock.auto_id}}
the id does not change...instead of it will always be id_ptposition-1-stock for all new forms. How do I get id_ptposition-2-stock using django tag?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has 2 loops when it seems like it should be just one

```
$(document).ready(function(){

{% for forms in formset %}
  $(".{{forms.stock.value}}").change( function(){
    var symbol = $(".{{forms.stock.value}} option:selected").text();

    $.ajax({
      url: "{% url 'inventory:get_position' ptinventory_obj.id date %}",
      type: "GET",
      data: { 'product': product },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        $(".{{forms.id.value}}_ouput").html(data.price);
      }
    });   
  });
{% endfor %}
});
```

Comment: Edited. Loop once. but when I add a form, the ouput appears on all forms and fail to query.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed that but the problem still there. I now realize the newly created form has None class which means the form.id.value is none before save. The inline position is not created yet. How do I give id to a formset instance that is not saved yet?